# webview not working, webview.loadUrl not working

Tags: android, android-webview

My webview.loadUrl code is not working. Whats the problem?

```
WebView wv;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wv.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    wv.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    wv.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    String url="http://www.google.com";
    wv.loadUrl(url);
}
```

Comment: Have you give internet permission in your manifest?

Answer (score 0):

Create a class in your activity:

```
 private class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }
```

then do it like this:

```
 wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wv.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        wv.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        wv.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());
        String url="http://www.google.com";
        wv.loadUrl(url);
```

Comment: what is not working? where are you testing app, on real device or virtual?